# how to create a eclipse plugin communicate with CDT framework

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I would like to augment Eclipse CDT with my own plugin, without touching the CDT source files. For instance I would like to create my own custom project "XYZ" (say File->New->Project->XYZ) which should internally create CDT project.

Does Eclipse CDT provide an API for that?

Is there a documentation for it?

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the [extension points](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Findex.html)?

Comment: I can highly recommend to first have a look at http://www.vogella.com/eclipse.html and try out one of the tutorials on creating an Eclipse plugin.